# Nested If Then and For Statements

Tags: vba, excel

I know how to fix the error in the macro below, but not the why behind the fix. Why is the " _" causing problems in the second If...Then statement?

I can fix it by either deleting the " _" or inserting a line below it. However, I can't move the For Statement to the end of the If...Then statement.

```
Sub Loop_Link_Change_ROE()

Dim MyPath As String
Dim MyFile As String
Dim sLink As String
Dim sNewName As String
Dim tNewName As String
Dim varLinks As Variant
Dim i As Integer

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

MyPath = "P:\Department\Actuarial Archive\Reserves\2018Q2\Documentation\Data Recon\"
MyFile = Dir(MyPath)

Do While MyFile <> ""
If MyFile Like "*Analysis_Regions_Phys_CM_*.xl*" Then
Workbooks.Open Filename:=MyPath & MyFile, UpdateLinks:=0

varLinks = ActiveWorkbook.LinkSources(xlExcelLinks)

If Not IsEmpty(varLinks) Then _
For i = 1 To UBound(varLinks)

    If InStr(1, varLinks(i), "4Q17") Then sNewName = Replace(varLinks(i), "4Q17", "2Q18")
    If InStr(1, varLinks(i), "GA") Then tNewName = Replace(sNewName, "GA", "Mid(varLinks(i), 30, 2)")
    If InStr(1, varLinks(i), "GA") Then ActiveWorkbook.ChangeLink Name:=varLinks(i), NewName:=tNewName, Type:=xlExcelLinks

ActiveWorkbook.Close True

Next

End If

End If

MyFile = Dir

Loop

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: There's no reason to put that `_` there.

Comment: What's the error that you're getting? What happens with each of the two approaches you're suggesting?

Comment: You should read [ask]?

Comment: You are treating everything starting with For up until Next as a single line and you are still providing an End If. Using If .... Then _ should only be used with a single line underneath; the _ makes it seem like it is all on the same line and doesn't require an End If.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two basic forms using `If` in VBA

All one one line:

```
If {test} Then {something}
```

...in which case subsequent lines have no connection with the `If`

Using `End If` and multiple lines:

```
If {test} Then
   {something} 'one or more lines of code
End If
```

Your `_` is not doing anything useful there

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for the prompt and concise answer!

Answer (score 1):

Underscore is a line continuation in vb so if you use it then you do not need an "end if" for that if statement because the for loop line below is treated as if it were part of the previous line.